# Creating an Animation of the World from Discrete Blocks

Tags: matlab

Consider a map of the world. This map has been separated into 108 blocks, and I have been given data on each block. I thought if I could create an animation for each block, I could then merge all 108 animations to form an animation of the world. The following  script appears to create an animation for a single block.

> ncfile2 = 'mhw_severity.pc90.0to30.30to50.1981.2019.nc' ; % nc file
>
> lat=ncread(ncfile2,'lat'); lon=ncread(ncfile2,'lon');
>   ssta=ncread(ncfile2,'ssta');
>
> for i=1:1000
>       imagesc(lat,lon,ssta(:,:,i))
>       i
>       pause(0.001)
>   end

Is there a more efficient way that this can be achieved?

Comment: Is loading all files and plotting them together not possible?

Comment: @AnderBiguri I'm unsure of how to do this. My coding (MATLAB) skills are not great. Do you have any suggestions on what my new code would look like?

Comment: @AnderBiguri I have also ready concatenated all my files by using an interative code. I know just need to produce a graph.